# failed to start udev kernel device manager

Tags: raspbian, kernel, failure

After hardly rebooting my raspberry pi 2 running raspian it does not work anymore, when I turn it on everything works fine until this error message shows up repeatedly.

`[FAILED] Failed to start udev Kernel Device Manager`

The machine then goes to emergency mode.
I didn't find any answer online, any ideas?

Comment: Years ago, I had the same problem with udev after an Raspbian-update (it crashed, and/or reboot didn't work). But today, **good news: I updated Raspbian, an udev seems to be working fine** (even after reboots etc.)!
So I assume the problem has been solved by now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be interesting to know which version you are running, and if you happened to update packages recently.

I encountered a similar error message on my raspberry pi2 after upgrading to raspbian testing today (from stretch). However I fear that it may be caused by a full range of different reasons.

The more precise error message I got (from `journalctl -u systemd-udevd`) was:

```
Sep 27 16:33:46 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[10856]: /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Operation not permitted
```

It does not seem to be related to `lib/systemd/systemd-udevd` itself. Indeed, if I `systemctl restart` another service, I get a similar error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
Job for systemd-timesyncd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status systemd-timesyncd.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# journalctl  -xe
[...]
Sep 27 18:54:50 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[26811]: /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Operation not permitted
[...]
```

My understanding is that systemd runs binaries in an environment that clashes with a relocation that is used in `libarmmem.so`. That is either a bug in systemd (version 234-3 here), or in the package that provides `libarmmem.so` (`raspi-copies-and-fills`, version 0.6 from stretch here).

systemd of course is essential, while `raspi-copies-and-fills` is not (it's an important optimization, but the system can run without it). I solved my problem with the following interim solution:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt purge raspi-copies-and-fills
```

Clearly, I'll monitor the possible updates to `raspi-copies-and-fills` (so far at version 0.6), hoping to get both a bootable system and the fast `memcpy`'s.

Answer (score 7):

As of systemd 235-2 this still continues with the exact same error.

---

**For people landing here from google:**

If you see that after `apt dist-upgrade` that either `udev`, `journald` or even `timesyncd` are crashing,

Until `raspi-copies-and-fills`, is updated, purging it like [Emmanuel Thomé suggested](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73023/74721) is the only viable solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

Rebuilding raspi-copies-and-fills from https://github.com/bavison/arm-mem fixes this in buster.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my pi-3 and `raspi-copies-and-fills` installed. 
Udev/systemd 232-25+deb9u1 was the last working version. All updates to a newer udev version failed and i was always forced to revert to 232-25+deb9u1

Now i have removed `raspi-copies-and-fills` and updating to 239-7 worked without error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from Raspbian 8 to Raspbian 9.
After udev package was upgrading to latest backport version, the raspberry was booting in emergency mode :

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in,type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D
to try again to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintainence
(or type control-D to continue):
```

removing `raspi-copies-and-fills` solve it !!

Comment: And why would that help?

Comment: What is this `raspi-copies-and-fills`? Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today after upgrading to Raspbian buster.  I was able to get the system booting again after purging version 0.11 of raspi-copies-and-fills from recovery mode as per @emmanuel-thomé 's answer.

Given @vhdirk's answer (that a rebuild from arm-mem source works), here's how I rebuilt a new `raspi-copies-and-fills` package...

I pulled the upstream (arm-mem) and RPi-Distro repos, then bumped the version to 0.12 (the udev 241-5 package blacklists prior raspi-copies-and-fills versions).

```
git clone https://github.com/p00ya/arm-mem.git -b p00ya
cd arm-mem
debuild -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../raspi-copies-and-fills_0.12+nmu1_armhf.deb
```

This seems to work (tested with `sudo systemctl restart udev` after installation).